# Create Foreign Key in Mysql have error Cannot resolve table name close to

Tags: mysql

I have trouble in adding a foreign key. I have the following script:

```
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dbdemo;
    use dbdemo;

    CREATE TABLE categories(
        cat_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
        cat_name varchar(255) not null,
        cat_description text
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

    CREATE TABLE products(
        prd_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
        prd_name varchar(355) not null,
        prd_price decimal,
        cat_id int unsigned not null,
        constraint fk_cat
        FOREIGN KEY fk_cat( cat_id )
        REFERENCES categories( cat_id )
        ON UPDATE cascade
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

    CREATE TABLE vendors(
    vdr_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    vdr_name varchar(255)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE products
ADD COLUMN prod_vdr_id int unsigned not null;
```

Then I got error when I try to add a FOREIGN KEY :

```
ALTER TABLE products 
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_vendor(prod_vdr_id)
REFERENCES vendor(vdr_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Then I got this error:

```
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'dbdemo.#sql-565_35' (errno: 150)
```

If i run "Show Engine innodb status;" I got :

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
150430 15:30:00 Error in foreign key constraint of table dbdemo/#sql-565_35:
FOREIGN KEY fk_vendor(prod_vdr_id)
REFERENCES vendor(vdr_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE NO ACTION:
Cannot resolve table name close to:
(vdr_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Can anyone show me some light where went wrong? 
TQVM

Comment: Yout table is called `vendors`. But in FK you use `vendor` without `s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is VENDORS not VENDOR

```
ALTER TABLE products 
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_vendor(prod_vdr_id)
REFERENCES vendors(vdr_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```